# Children's story about moneyless / post-scarcity / communist world?

Tags: story-identification, mars

I have a vague memory of reading a story in my childhood and was hoping someone might be able to help me identify it. I've been googling all day and would be extremely grateful for any ideas! I'm not 100% certain on any of the following details, but they describe a rough impression I have of the story. Based on when I think I read it, the story must be at least 15 years old (2002 or earlier), but most likely 19+ years old (1998 or earlier).

- an alien from the Moon, Mars, or any planet (!) describes life/society on his home planet
- it's a moneyless society
- there's perhaps work, but it's based on ability and not linked to remuneration
- when he needs something, he just has to phone up, order what he likes, and then it's delivered. Example may have been a car? It might not be phoning but some other telecommunication method.
- he might be describing this to children from Earth. Either he's visiting Earth or they're visiting his planet.

I don't know if this was a short story or a comic or what. I think it's a simple story, say for children younger than at least 12.

Perhaps I only read the beginning, but it seemed like a simple story, of an alien sharing his way of life, without much plot or action. It could even be so simple it was just a very short story a teacher wrote, or something printed on an activity sheet, rather than a fully published piece of fiction, so sorry!

Comment: Although you've got a lot of information there, take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Since it's a supposed to be a children's story, it's most likely neither _Stranger in a Strange Land_, nor The Culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds rather like *[The Conquest of Mars](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13507522-the-conquest-of-mars)* by W.C.H. Chalk. I read it in my early teens, but I've not been able to find a copy since.

From memory:

- he might be describing this to children from Earth. Either he's visiting Earth or they're visiting his planet.

Not children, but soldiers who've arrived with the expectation of conquering Mars, and they provide the plot device to explain Martian society.

- it's a moneyless society

At one point, a Martian child asks one of the Terrans what money is, and he shows her "coloured pieces of paper".

- there's perhaps work, but it's based on ability and not linked to remuneration

The first Martian encountered in the story is a farmer who is growing a field of cabbages. He grows them because he enjoys the work, not to sell the cabbages.

- when he needs something, he just has to phone up, order what he likes, and then it's delivered. Example may have been a car? It might not be phoning but some other telecommunication method.

The Martian society was highly automated. The Terrans are taken to see a factory that's building entire houses, rolling them onto lorries, which then deliver them to whoever has ordered them. The only 'payment' required is a signature.

Large goods are acquired by ordering them and signing for them when they arrive. Smaller things, like food, are just freely available. At one point, most of the Terrans have been at a cafe while their leader meets with some Martian bigwig, and I remember them enthusing to him that they just took cakes - I remember the line "You didn't even have to sign for them!"

Other details:

I believe all the Terrans in the book had alliterative names. The only one I really remember was Commander Kragg. I think there was also Peter P?, a Terran who became enamoured of the Martian lifestyle.

The book built on an earlier book, with a title I don't remember; that book was about a professor and probably his student who figured out that there were certain points on Earth where the gravity of Earth and the Moon cancelled out, and one could easily travel between them. I believe the Nazca lines in Peru were markers for this effect.

In this book, the humans reached Mars from Earth by taking advantage of this effect.

The books were relatively short, and illustrated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's a lot in common. Details that differ could easily be explained by my poor memory. I wish it was easy to get a copy. I looked at other books he wrote. Most of them seem to be published as/under Instant Readers, Booster Books or Heinemann Educational Books. This fits a detail I left out, I think I read this at school. He also has a book called 'Man From Mars'. Wondering if it explores the same society but from one particular Martian, in line with my memory (though equally happy to believe I was thinking of the farmer in Conquest of Mars)

Comment: I managed to find a reasonably priced used copy for sale on a Swedish used book site. It's on its way... will update once I receive it and have time to read through it. Let me know if you'd like to borrow it afterwards!

Comment: Received it now and I'm certain this is it. Marked as answer. A lot of the moneyless, post-scarcity and automation stuff is summarised quite neatly in about 4 pages early in the book, and very much capture the memory I had and what you described. I probably stopped reading soon after this as which is why I didn't remember any other details! Again, let me know if you'd like to borrow it down the line :)